# Invoke emacsclient with a smaller font

Tags: emacsclient, fonts, command-line-arguments

For a certain application, I would like to start up emacsclient, but with a slightly smaller font.  I can do it for a running emacs by eval'ing:

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :height 90)
```

But how to do it with command-line arguments just for the frame opened by emacsclient?  The -F flag looks promising, but I'm not sure of the syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-F` flag takes an alist (short for association list), which is a list where each element is a cons cell of the form `(parameter . value)`. One of the available parameters is `font`, so to specify e.g. "Consolas 12", you'd say

```
emacsclient -F '((font . "Consolas 12"))'
```

Comment: Thanks, rpluim.  That answers the question.  Is there a way to say something like, the default font at a smaller size?

Comment: The only way I see to get that is if you define a fontset based on the default font, but at a smaller size, and then use that in the font specification.